# Display data from Meteor.call function with Flowrouter and trackerreact.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, flow-router

I have this code,

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import TrackerReact from 'meteor/ultimatejs:tracker-react';
const username = "test";
export default class TasksWrapper extends TrackerReact(React.Component){
    constructor(){
        super();
        Meteor.call('getMyInfo', (error,data)=>{
            if(error){
                alert(error);
            }else{
                this.username = data.username;
            }
        });
    }
    render(){
        return (
        <div className="container">
        <div className="row profile">
            {this.username}
        </div></div>
        )
    }
}
```

The line of codes above is not working. What I want is to display the username of the user in the div with class name of "row profile".

When I run this codes, I get only "test". It is displayed in the page. What I want to display is the usernae. for example, "John".

How can I do it? Any sample?

Comment: Where is "getMyInfo" defined ?

Comment: At the server. I put it in server folder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store `username` by `state` so that when `username` changes, React will re-render the component:

```
export default class TasksWrapper extends TrackerReact(React.Component) {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      username: ''
    };
    Meteor.call('getMyInfo', (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        alert(error);
      } else {
        this.setState({username: data.username});
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row profile">
          {this.state.username}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```